# Index 0 Requested with a size of 0 Error in SQLITE DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

There is data in the database (2 rows to be precise) with info in each.

Here is the code (that matters, not all of it) from the DBADAPTER:

```
// Field Names:
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_DEVICE = "device";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String KEY_DEVID = "devid";

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_DEVICE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_DEVID};
    public static final String[] DEVID_KEY = new String[] {KEY_DEVID};

    // Column Numbers for each Field Name:
    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
    public static final int COL_DEVICE = 1;
    public static final int COL_TYPE = 2;
    public static final int COL_DEVID = 3;

    // DataBase info:
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbDevices";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainDevices";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10; // The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.

    //SQL statement to create database
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
            "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
            + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_DEVICE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_DEVID + " TEXT NOT NULL "
            + ");";

    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // Get a specific row (by devid)
        public String getDevName(String devid) {
            String name;
            String where = KEY_DEVID + " like '%" + devid + "%'";
            Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                            where, null, null, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                name = c.getString(COL_DEVICE);
            return name;
        }
```

Here is the code that calls it:

```
String incomingMessage = " ";
incomingMessage = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
devName = devDB.getDevName(incomingMessage);
```

And I know that this is getting it info because it logs:
`03-16 15:39:47.072: V/String(18073): 5122`

Whenever I run this I get the error:

```
03-16 15:39:47.122: W/System.err(18073): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
03-16 15:39:47.122: W/System.err(18073):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
03-16 15:39:47.122: W/System.err(18073):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
03-16 15:39:47.132: W/System.err(18073):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
03-16 15:39:47.132: W/System.err(18073):    at com.ti.cc3x.android.DBAdapter.getDevName(DBAdapter.java:121)
03-16 15:39:47.132: W/System.err(18073):    at com.ti.cc3x.android.broadcastListener$1.run(broadcastListener.java:112)
03-16 15:39:47.132: W/System.err(18073):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I have tried checking for not null cursor. All that does is tell me nothing. I know there is data where I am asking it to look I just do not know why it will not show it. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong? Thank you!

Comment: When posting logcat, please put it in a code block for readability. Same usually goes for any kind of stacktrace or other lengthy error messages.

Comment: Also, I seriously recommend using a third-party library for SQLite on Android unless you are a skilled DBA and/or have a practical reason not to use a lib. Android's default implementation, while very capable, is very cumbersome and prone to developer error. I made a small, open source `DatabaseManager` class which simplifies threading and synchronization available on [GitHub](https://github.com/JakarCo/databasemanager). But I'd really recommend going with something like SugarORM, GreenDao, or ActiveAndroid (there are others, too).

Comment: And for a potential solution, you are passing `in.readLine() + "\r\n"` (\r\n being a line separator) to `getDevName`, so your query is actually for `LIKE '%line_that_i_read\r\n%'`, so you aren't getting any rows returned, thus the index 0 is unavailable.

Comment: This worked. I removed the line separator and used the code provided by Daniel Nugent and it output what I needed! Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085666/index-0-requested-with-a-size-of-0-error-in-sqlite-db/29085919#29085919) from @bwegs regarding the call to `getWritableDatabase()`.

Try using the `selectionArgs` since it's cleaner. Check the return value of `moveToFirst()`, and be sure to close your cursor to avoid memory leaks.

```
 public String getDevName(String devid) {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();  //get db if not done so already, you may have already done this in code not shown

    String name = null;
    String where = KEY_DEVID + " like ?";
    String[] selectionArgs =  new String[] {"%"+ devid + "%" };
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, selectionArgs , null, null, null, null);

    //Only use cursor if moveToFirst() succeeds
    //this will make it so that you don't get the CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        name = c.getString(COL_DEVICE);
    }

    c.close(); //close your cursor to avoid memory leak!

    db.close(); //close here if you call getWritableDatabase() in beginning of this function

    //This will return null if no results from query
    return name;
}
```

Comment: This worked along side Jakar's comment on removing the line separator from the incomingMessage variable (which I do not remember why I put there in the first place) Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Just a thought: often times returning null is useful to indicate errors, but it can also be beneficial to `return "error";` instead so that you aren't subject to null pointer exceptions later and if the name gets printed regardless, then it's a seamless way to tell your users about errors. But, that's of course subject to personal preferences (or company preferences) and the situation.

Comment: Good point @Jakar.  We usually do null checks on Strings, that's the standard convention where I work now, but it's good to know about other perspectives.  Also, good catch on the line separator issue!

Comment: this answer is being discussed at [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288191/how-to-handle-a-copy-cat-that-eventually-edits-their-way-to-an-original-answer)

Answer (score 15):

Are you using `SQLiteOpenHelper`? If so you you need to set your database variable `db` to your database **before** attempting to read from or write to it like so:

```
db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

... your new `getDevName(..)` method should look something like this:

```
public String getDevName(String devid) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String name;
    String where = KEY_DEVID + " like '%" + devid + "%'";
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    name = c.getString(COL_DEVICE);

    db.close(); // close your db connection when you're done with it

    return name;
}
```

#### From the Android Developer documentation:

> **public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase () -**
>   The first time this is called, the database will be opened and onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and/or onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) will be called.
>   Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database.) Errors such as bad permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.